# Pass variables to evaluated coffeescript

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, sandbox

I've got a situation where I'd like to be able to pass certain variables into and out of a Coffeescript evaluation environment. The situation looks like this:

```
coffee = require('coffee-script');

exports.run = function(req,res){
  var program = req.query.program;
  var inputs = req.query.inputs;
  var outputs = coffee.eval(program);
  res.json(outputs);
};
```

Basically, `inputs` will be an object listing input parameters for the user's program, and `outputs` will pass those back to the web interface for prominent display.

How can I expose variables and functions to the sandboxed Coffeescript environment?

Comment: Take a look at the [CoffeeScript REPL's `eval` function](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/blob/5162472f16765ff85b41057993188955b947a8e3/src/repl.coffee#L23-L30). Hopefully it can give you some nice ideas =D. Beware, though, that the `locals` argument of `CoffeeScript.compile` is not a documented feature, so it's probably not part of a stable API ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround that I'm using for the time being. I'm making the user's Coffeescript program return a function that then gets evaluated.

Inputs:

```
{ x:5, y:7 }
```

Server side:

```
outputs = coffee.eval(program + '\nmain')(inputs,outputs);
```

User code:

```
main = (i,o) ->
    o.z = i.x*5 + i.y
```

A little messy, but it works for the time being.